# Cannot write Excel document using JXL ("Sheet name too long - truncating")

Tags: java, excel, selenium-webdriver, frameworks, jxl

I want to write excel sheet and for that I write a code, but when my program execute in the object WritableSheet it get the below warning. 
May I know where I am going wrong?? Also, I am using keydriven framework for writing a sheet.

```
Warning:  Sheet name D:\eclipse-jee-kepler-SR1-win32\Workspace\AutomationFramework\configuration\GmailTestSuite.xls too long - truncating
Warning:  : is not a valid character within a sheet name - replacing
Warning:  \ is not a valid character within a sheet name - replacing
```

Code which I am using for writing a sheet:

```
public class WritableData {

    Workbook wbook;
    WritableWorkbook wwbCopy;
    String ExecutedTestCasesSheet;
    WritableSheet shSheet;

    public WritableData(String testSuitePath, String string) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        try {
            wbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(testSuitePath));
            wwbCopy = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File(testSuitePath));
            // shSheet=wwbCopy.getSheet(1);
            shSheet = wwbCopy.createSheet(testSuitePath, 1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            System.out.println("Exception message" + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void shSheet(String strSheetName, int iColumnNumber, int iRowNumber,
            String strData) throws WriteException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        WritableSheet wshTemp = wwbCopy.getSheet(strSheetName);
        WritableFont cellFont = null;
        WritableCellFormat cellFormat = null;

        if (strData.equalsIgnoreCase("PASS")) {
            cellFont = new WritableFont(WritableFont.TIMES, 12);
            cellFont.setColour(Colour.GREEN);
            cellFont.setBoldStyle(WritableFont.BOLD);

            cellFormat = new WritableCellFormat(cellFont);
            cellFormat.setBorder(Border.ALL, BorderLineStyle.THIN);
        }

        else if (strData.equalsIgnoreCase("FAIL")) {
            cellFont = new WritableFont(WritableFont.TIMES, 12);
            cellFont.setColour(Colour.RED);
            cellFont.setBoldStyle(WritableFont.BOLD);

            cellFormat = new WritableCellFormat(cellFont);
            cellFormat.setBorder(Border.ALL, BorderLineStyle.THIN);
        }

        else {
            cellFont = new WritableFont(WritableFont.TIMES, 12);
            cellFont.setColour(Colour.BLACK);

            cellFormat = new WritableCellFormat(cellFont);
            cellFormat.setBorder(Border.ALL, BorderLineStyle.THIN);
            cellFormat.setWrap(true);
        }

        Label labTemp = new Label(iColumnNumber, iRowNumber, strData,
                cellFormat);
        try {
            wshTemp.addCell(labTemp);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void closeFile() {
        try {
            // write the value in work book
            wwbCopy.write();
            // wwbCopy.close();

            // Closing the original work book
            wbook.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First you should understand the terminology.

*Workbook* = the whole Excel document, it is the whole content of the file.

*Sheet* = part of the workbook, one Excel "page". A workbook can have multiple sheets.

Sheet name is in the small tab in the bottom of your Excel file. Pass there something shorter and more useful, such as `Data`.

[image]

---

There are multiple problems in your code. I will discuss some of them which are related to your question.

Here you open the file/workbook:

```
wbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(testSuitePath));
```

On the next line, you create a new workbook with the same name - **by this you overwrite your previous file** so it is empty now:

```
wwbCopy = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File(testSuitePath));
```

And finally here you create one new sheet with an incorrect name:

```
shSheet = wwbCopy.createSheet(testSuitePath, 1);
```

You shouldn't name your sheet the same as your file.

---

And by the way, in Java you should use `'/'` in your file names, not `'\'`. Java will turn all the slashes into the correct character according to the target operating system.

As for your exception handling, read [Is it really that bad to catch a general exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21938/2886891) or [In Java, what is the difference between catch a generic exception and a specific exception (eg. IOException?)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5979501/2886891). Do not catch a generic exception.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply, actually in createSheet it take createSheet(String, int.arg1). So, how can we pass sheet name like you told?

Comment: Try createSheet("data", 1) :-) supposed that the number means the sheet index within the workbook, check if it starts from 0 or from 1.

Comment: via your last comment I am not getting that warning but what happen now I have given sheet name on which I have to write say "Data" as you suggest. But when I am executing a program it delete all the other workbook which it contains and only create one. Why is it so?

Comment: Can you please let me know how to write in existing sheet? Actually I am trying to set status of executed test cases but whenever I'll execute the cases it create new workbook. I read your editable content but don't understand that how I can write in sheet? :(

Comment: I edited my answer so the text which answers your last question is now **in bold**. You cannot get a fish on StackOverflow, but a fishing rod instead.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are passing path to excel file in your "testSuitePath" variable. Kindly debug and make sure that you are passing correct value in testSuitePath.

Hope it helps